# Translating the insert fact from Prolog to core.logic

Tags: clojure, prolog, clojure-core.logic

I'm toying around with core.logic and trying to translate some Prolog code and run into an endless recursion for the `insert` facts (taken from R.A.O'Keefe's "Craft of Prolog"):

```
 insert(L, X, [X|L]).
 insert([H|T], X, [H|L]) :-
        insert(T,X,L).
```

This is what I've come up so far (please note that the first two arguments are exchanged to match up with `conso` parameter list):

```
 (defn insert [x l nl]
    (conde
      [(conso x l nl)]
      [(fresh [h t]
         (conso h t l)
         (insert x t l)
         (conso h l nl))]))
```

The problem I have is that the last two facts from these midje tests will never return.
The first one works just fine as is expected since this only requires the first `conso` clause.

```
   (fact "Inserting works"
         (run* [q] (insert 1 [2] q)) => '((1 2)))
         (run* [q] (insert 1 [2 3] q)) => '((1 2 3)))
   (fact "We can retrieve the inserted data"
         (run* [q] (insert q [2] '(1 2))) => '(1))
   (fact "We can retrieve the list data, too"
         (run* [q] (insert 1 q '(1 2))) => '((2))))
```

I guess I'm overlooking something obvious, but what?

**Edit:** The facts don't reflect the behavior of the Prolog code correctly. The right behavior is like this:

```
   ?- insert([2,3], 1, Q).
   Q = [1, 2, 3] ;
   Q = [2, 1, 3] ;
   Q = [2, 3, 1].
```

So, the second checkable should actually be

```
 (fact "Inserting works"
       (run* [q] (insert 1 [2 3] q)) => '((1 2 3) (2 1 3) (2 3 1)))
```

Comment: use `NL=[H|R]`. can't use `L` instead of `R` there, `L` is already used as an argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to make the recursive insert clause last:

```
(defn insert [x l nl]
    (conde
      [(conso x l nl)]
      [(fresh [h t]
         (conso h t l)
         (conso h l nl)
         (insert x t l))]))
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll have to think about why the change in order makes a difference here.

Comment: To account for the right behavior of the Prolog version (cf. my edit above), `l` should only be used in the first `conso` term and replaced with a fresh `l1` otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

The Prolog code can be transcribed almost verbatim as core.logic also supports matching.

```
(defne inserto [L, X, L*] 
    ([L, X, (X . L)]) 
    ([(H . T), X, (H . L)] (inserto T, X, L)))
```

Note that I've kept the order of the Prolog version, rather than the inverted order of the first two logical variables in your version.

```
user=> (run* [q] (inserto [2] 1 q))
((1 2))
user=> (run* [q] (inserto [2 3] 1 q))
((1 2 3))
user=> (run* [q] (inserto [2] q [1 2]))
(1)
user=> (run* [q] (inserto q 1 [1 2]))
((2))
```

Comment: Please note that @Ankur answered the actual question, but I figured this was useful to point out and ill-suited for a comment.

Comment: Thanks for this hint at matching which indeed makes it way more easy. As I found out, however, this solution does not match the behavior of the Prolog version, which was probably to me getting the midje facts wrong (I've edited the question to correct it).
It needs only a small change, though: exchange the use of 'L' in the recursive code with L1, i.e. `([H . T), X, (H . L1)]) (inserto T, X, L1)`. This allows for more results to be found via backtracking.